# how to use jquery to avoid session timeout for content inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have some content from another web application in my web application shown using an iframe. Both applications are on the same websphere server.

Unfortunately the other web application has a very short session timeout and I end up with session timeouts in my iframe. What I want to ask is whether or not there is a way to send an ajax style heartbeat (or some other method) to the iframe to stop the session timeout. The catch is that I cannot modify the other web application.

The iframe on my page looks like...

```
<iframe id="posManagerFrame" name="posManagerFrame" class="posManagerFrame"></iframe>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an interval that fires and ajax call to the iFrame, this should keep your session active.

Comment: thanks... exactly what i was thinking. But the tricky bit is what action / target do i specify in my ajax call? I don't think the other app inside the iframe has any ajax actions. Is there some fake request I can hit or something else I can do that will result in nothing changing in the iframe?

Comment: just call any page in the application, it doesn't need to return anything, just the fact that you are calling the page from the client should be enough to keep the session alive.

Comment: I am interested in this, how do you keep alive the iframe content , unaltering current page in the iframe? Any example?